# Add japanese input support

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-layout, language

In Ubuntu 18.04 and forward I used to install Japanese(Mozc) software that allowed me to change among the different syllabaries using this tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JapaneseInput . It was a graphical install no commands required. It just takes installing Japanese language support and then you can add it to the keyboard layouts. In Linux Mint I successfully installed the language but then it doesn't appears in the available layouts

Am using Linux Mint 20 . Is there any way I can use this software or something similar in Linux Mint?

I also tried installing ibus and ibus-mozc in Linux Mint using:

```
sudo apt install ibus
sudo apt install ibus-mozc
```

This sort of worked for me but it breaks my Linux Mint languages layout and shortcuts for changing layouts.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) explain what you did, what commands you ran. Don't expect us to go read some other page, all details need to be in the question. Also, that way we can know what you actually ran, and not only what the tutorial suggests. ii) explain _how_ it doesn't work. Were there any error messages? What happens when you try this?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu worked? What version of Mint does not? What exactly is *not* working on Mint?

Comment: @terdon I think now my question makes more sense, mind checking it?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Versions added

Comment: Much better, thank you!